# hudson detecting failure when builds are succeeding

Tags: hudson

our hudson build is succeeding, but hudson is somehow reporting a failure.

what is the criteria that hudson uses for determining failure and success?

BTW, Our build updates a .xml file with the results of the test. I've checked, and it appears that hudson is correctly updating this file (The modification time matches)

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the last few lines of the console output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the link for the build that failed (#123 for instance), and then go to Console Output link on the left.  That log will tell you what step of the build failed.

Note that just because the build *of the software* succeeded, doesn't mean the entire build process succeeded.  You might have a final step that, for instance, deletes some intermediate, unnecessary files.  If one of those files was in use and couldn't be deleted (causing the batch file to return an error), then the step failed, and as a result the entire build is marked as a failure.

Comment: Similarly, if any post-build actions in the Hudson configuration can't be run (missing resource, etc.), Hudson will fail the build.

Comment: What the other two said is true. In addition, every time you use a Windows batch task or a shell script task, success and failure are determined on the return value of the batch/script. If you don't set one explicitly, it will use the return value of the last command that ran. Be aware that not all programs adhere to the standard that 0 is success and not 0 is failure. Examples are: robocopy and db2 (the commandline tool that can execute an sql script).